# Broken imges after moving wordpress website from localhost to server

Tags: images

after moving my wordpress website from localhost to server, I don't see any images anymore. All my images are shown with a broken icon in my website. However im my media library they all look great.
Any Help plaease !
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is easy if you can see the images in the Media Section.

Check your links and let us know why the URLs are wrong.

You may have problems with hard-coding or using relative links.

Why not check yor theme and consider this [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/linking-theme-files-directories/) you need to use correct functions to show the images.

Comment: Yes the URLs changed after uploading the website into live server. Now I changed the directory of my images and my problem is finallly solved. Thanx a lot !

Comment: Glad it worked @OkKo